# imagelist images not available in child form .net winform

Tags: winforms, imagelist

I have a dll that contains a form that is being inherited by other forms.  The parent form has an imagelist with several images in it and two of these are being used in toolbar buttons. It has been working for a long time but I had to add a toolbar button and an image to go with it.

The new button with the new image displays in the designer correctly in the base form, but in an existing child form, the button doesn't display in the toolbar in the designer (although it shows up at runtime with no image).  In the child form, the imagelist is present with all the original images, but the new image that I added to the base form does not appear in it.

I have tried several different icons with the same result.  Interestingly when I point the new tb button to one of the images that has always existed, everything is fine in the child.  It just won't handle any of the new images (I've tried icons & bitmaps).  I would try to delete the toolbar and imagelist and re-create it but unfortunately I don't know where the existing images are located to be able to add them back to the new imagelist.

(VS 2010, VB.NET - but C# answers are most welcome!)

Comment: "I don't know where the existing images are located" - Maybe this is the key ? Could be a path problem if the newly added images are referenced with a relative path..

Comment: Once I select an image file from a folder via the imagelist designer object, I no longer see any record of where the file is, anywhere in my source.  I've been assuming that the VS imports the file then and there and stores it somewhere within the project, but I don't know.

Comment: Try adding the image as a resource to the project and reference this in the designer..

Comment: That did not work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. My parent form have an image list wich I use to  present my own control box (min, max, close). All the child forms inherit from this form and everything is ok if I don't change the elements of the list. But when I add an element or change the Image index of the control buttons, this is not reflected in the child forms. Sadly I haven't fixed it yet but what I did is:

1. Declare the Image list as public in the designer of the parent form
2. Determine the forms that don't reflect the desired change
3. Set Manually the desired change by adding the image to the inherited IMageLIst and changing the image index in all and every form with the bug

This is not what I intended to do by designing a parent form, but it works.